# Get redirect url of iframe in Angular

Tags: html, angular, iframe, angular-material

I am using an iframe in Angular. I want to fetch redirect URL of iframe. How can I do that?

In my iframe, the user will click on a button, so he will be redirected to another URL. I want to fetch that URL. Is there any way to do that?

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 1500px;" 
        (load)="closeIframe();" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe">
</iframe>
```